# NetworkBoundResource in RxSwift

Tags: android, ios, swift, reactjs, rx-swift

I'm an android developer but quite new to `Swift/Rxswift`, I was trying to code an equivalent for [NetworkBoundResource](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.kt) but I'm not sure it's possible to do it using `Rxswift` as it lacks the equivalent to MediatorLiveData and the merge operator wouldn't let you assign a closure for each observable.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful function factory. You call it by passing in instructions on how to retrieve data from the DB and network and how to save data to the DB. It the generates an operator that you can use in a flatMap to get a result from a request.

It will first emit the value from the DB, and then make the network request. If the network request is successful, the operator will emit the result and also send it to the DB to store.

I would be called like: `let getResource = resource(loadFromDb: /* loader */, network: /* requester */, save: /* saver */)` Then you could use `getRequest` in a flatMap over an Observable of RequestType.

```
func resource<RequestType, ResultType>(loadFromDb: @escaping (RequestType) -> Observable<ResultType>,
                                       network: @escaping (RequestType) -> Observable<ResultType>,
                                       save: AnyObserver<(RequestType, ResultType)>
    ) -> (RequestType) -> Observable<ResultType> {
    return { request in
        return Observable.create { observer in
            let netResult = network(request)
                .share(replay: 1)

            let dispose1 = Observable.concat(loadFromDb(request), netResult)
                .bind(to: observer)

            let dispose2 = netResult
                .map { (request, $0) }
                .bind(to: save)

            return Disposables.create([dispose1, dispose2])
        }
    }
}
```

Just a thought.